# Zabbix Agent Auto Registration - Zabbix Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, zabbix, zabbix-api, zabbix-custom-reports

I am trying to register Zabbix agent to Zabbix server UI automatically but seems i am missing something but when i am trying to do it via UI(Manually) it is working. can someone help me to do it.

**My configurations -**

```
/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf

Server=127.0.0.1,{zabbix-server-ip}
ServerActive=DNS Name
HostMetadata=ubuntu (string why which i am doing configuration in UI)
```

any though on this would be appreciated.

Comment: first, you need to set **Server** and **ServerActive** both IP or DNS of zabbix server. For auto discovery, you need to set rules in zabbix UI with HostMetadataItem. check if link will help you. https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/discovery/auto_registration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you need to set **Server** and **ServerActive** both **IP or DNS** of zabbix server.

For auto discovery, you need to set rules in zabbix UI/frontend with **HostMetadata** under ***Configuration → Actions.***

Check if link will help you.

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/discovery/auto_registration

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a script for auto-registration of the Zabbix agent to Zabbix server.

For auto discovery, you need to set rules in Zabbix UI/frontend with **HostMetadata** under **Configuration → Actions**. [Follow This](https://github.com/Shubhamjain6197/zabbix-agent-auto-registration)

Then you can move ahead with script execution on agent

```
#Note - This script takes zabbixserverip metadatastring as input at runtime sh script.sh internal-dns-name free-string
#!/bin/bash
zabbixserverip=$1
metadatastring=$2
apt update -y
apt install zabbix-agent
sed -i -- 's/Server=127.0.0.1/Server='$zabbixserverip'/g' /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
echo "ServerActive=$zabbixserverip" >> /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
echo "HostMetadata=$metadatastring" >> /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
systemctl restart zabbix-agent
systemctl status zabbix-agent
```

Comment: make sure, hostname of zabbix agent is same on zabbix server and zabbix agent conf.

Answer (score 0):

You are configuring `Server` and `ServerActive` wrong: both need to be set to the IP/DNS of the Zabbix Proxy/Server, no the local IP/DNS.